# Is $H$ a subgroup of $\mathcal{S}_4$? Is $H$ a left/right coset of a subgroup of $\mathcal{S}_4$?

Tags: group-theory

**Question.** Let $$H:=\{f\in\mathcal{S}_4: f\cdot1=2\}.$$

**Attempt.** The permutations that in $H$ are $$\{(1\ 2), (1\ 2\ 3), (1\ 2\ 3\ 4), (1\ 2)(3\ 4), (1\ 2\ 4\ 3), (1\ 2\ 4)\}.$$ Since the identity permutation is absent in $H$; it follows that $H$ is not a subgroup of $\mathcal{S}_4$.

Unfortunately this is where it goes a bit pear-shaped. I'm not quite sure where to start in showing whether it is a coset or not. Any hints on where to proceed from here would be very appreciated.

Comment: As a hint, if $f \cdot 1 = 2$, then $g \cdot 1 = 2 \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}g \in {\rm Stab}_G(1) \Leftrightarrow g \in f{\rm Stab}_G(1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $(1\, 2)H$. 
If $H$ is a coset, it should be a subgroup.